# How to edit a device driver file(.sys)

Tags: usb, driver, hid

How I can edit a `device driver` file `(.sys)` and I want to update the `Report Descriptor` file. I want to transpose the X and Y value of USB HID device driver. Please help me to transpose the X & Y value in an HID device.

Answer (score 1):

use a binary editor, or if you are *really* careful, `vi`. note that whatever you do, leave strings exactly the same length or you will almost definitely crash your operating system.

assuming you are using Windows, good old debug.exe will work fine as a binary editor. the interface is a bit obscure though.

```
C:\Users\jc>echo bleah > test.sys

C:\Users\jc>debug test.sys
-e100
17DD:0100  62.31   6C.32   65.33   61.34   68.35
-w
Writing 00008 bytes
-q

C:\Users\jc>type test.sys
12345
```

on the line following -e100, I was typing the new values and hitting the spacebar; when done I hit <enter>.

Comment: And of course this works only if the driver has no digital signature and OS allows unsigned drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any static disassembler for Win32/Win64. This way you will better see the code instructions, function names, and be able to find your target easily (otherwise reading machine code directly it's for priviledged minds).

One example can be "PEBrowse Professional" (free) but there are many other out there. The one I cited is verified to open 64-sys of Win10.